# Can asymptotic series include negative exponents (Laurent series)?

Tags: asymptotics, mathematical-physics

An series $\{a_n\}$ to a function $f(x)$ is defined as

$$
f(x) - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n\sim a_{N+1}x^{N+1}
$$

as $x \rightarrow x_0$ for all N.

I have just heard, that the exponents $n$ do not have to be integers, but fractional values for example are allowed too.

What about the $n$ being negative, are Laurent series potentially valid asymptotic series approximating some functions too?

If not, why not?

Comment: They are valid. Look up the asymptotic series for factorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some functions, one can find asymptotic series that have nothing to do with powers of $x$ at all. So negative powers, fractional powers, all are possible. In general, asymptotic series expansions for a function $f(x)$ have the form

$$ f(x) \sim \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x). $$

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) for some examples of such asymptotic series.